# MVC3 Partial with no caching on page with caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

In my MVC3 Project I use some output caching with the `OutputCache` attribute set on the action. However there are certain sections on this page that I dont want to cache ever.

Is it possible to have some partials in my view that overrides the pages caching?

Comment: Were you ever able to get a solution for this?  It seems that the link below goes does the opposite (caches the partial but not the page, while you seem to want to cache the page but not the partial).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now get proper donut caching by downloading the MvcDonutCaching NuGet package. See http://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/ and http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3 for more information.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to work with MVC DonutCaching and SqlDependency? In my action `Index` use the `DonutOutputCache`. I have an action `ProjectList` that generates a list of projects. How can I use `SqlDependency` in `ProjectList (partial)` action?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are 'supposed' to be able to do this. 
See:
[Partial Views Caching in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750512/partial-views-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Also I use a method to disable caching for controllers here:

[Disable browser cache for entire ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache/5546328#5546328)

Comment: Hmmm, didnt seem to work properly getting this error: "OutputCacheAttribute for child actions only supports Duration, VaryByCustom, and VaryByParam values. Please do not set CacheProfile, Location, NoStore, SqlDependency, VaryByContentEncoding, or VaryByHeader values for child actions."

Comment: What values did you set on the child action?

Comment: [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")] and the page itself had [OutputCache(Duration = 36000, VaryByParam = "id")]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is the answer: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/28/tip-trick-implement-donut-caching-with-the-asp-net-2-0-output-cache-substitution-feature.aspx

You basically have two options:

1. Refactor the page so that rather than caching the entire page,
   you identify all the specific pieces (controls, partials, etc) that
   should be cached.  (boo)
2. Use output substitution blocks as Scott
   Guthrie describes in the link.  (boo as well unless the replacement
   is just simple text)

Answer (score 0):

This is called donut caching and isn't supported out of the box in MVC3. Check out my similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685906/is-donut-caching-available-in-asp-net-mvc-3). Specifically, Jan Jongboom's Moth library which he suggests can do this (though I cannot confirm or deny this)