# ASP.Net MVC Caching & Javascript Initialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For best performance, it is best practice to place Javascript code at the bottom of a page.  Now I have a Partial View in MVC which I am loading using the `Html.Action` method.  I am also using the `OutputCaching` attribute in order to cache the controller action response and hence speed up server response.  This is my issue:

Within such a partial view, I have some Javascript which initialises a javascript carousel.  The ID of the carousel element is generated on the fly within the same Partial View itself.  In order to gain the best performance, the javascript code is 'registered' within the `ViewContext` and then rendered at the end of the page.

Now since I have `OutputCaching` enabled, the registration of such javascript code with the `ViewContext` is done only once when the item is not cached cause else, no logic is executed.

A workaround to this solution is not to include the javascript code at the end of the page but as part of the PartialView itself and hence it is cached with the entire content of the Partial View.

Is there anything you can suggest to cache the Partial View and register the Javascript code at the end of the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partial Views Caching in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750512/partial-views-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-3)