# Caching an entire partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, razor

Is it possible to cache an entire partial view?  I can't find any reference on how to actually set the caching attribute in the aspx view itself.  I have a navigation div that is in a partial view and that never changes, so would like to cache it.

```
<html>
<body>

@Html.Partial("_Nav")   

@RenderBody() 
</body>
</html>
```

_Nav.cshtml:

```
/* I want to cache this html */
<div id="menu">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the partialview in an actionresult and use

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
```

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750512/partial-views-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-3)